# Can't change img and nicknames picked from steamapi

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-promise, steam

I need to sync images and nicknames using this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/steamapi

I'm pretty new to promises and I got to this point,

my code:

```
    const SteamAPI = require('steamapi');
const steam = new SteamAPI('my steam token');

// Myself, image
const imageUser1= steam.getUserSummary("76561198145216800").then(function(k){
    return k.avatar.large;
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("Didn't make it")
})
imageUser1.then(function(u){
    console.log("yes")
    document.getElementById("Img1Credits1").src = "" + k;
})

// Crowbaria, image
const imageUser2= steam.getUserSummary("76561198175487278").then(function(k) {
    return k.avatar.large;
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("Didn't make it")
})
imageUser2.then(function(u){
    document.getElementById("Img1Credits2").src = "" + k;
})

// //\\--------------------------\\//
// Myself, nickname
const nicknameFromAPI1= steam.getUserSummary("76561198145216800").then(function(k){
    return k.nickname;
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("Didn't make it")
})
nicknameFromAPI1.then(function(u){
    var nickname1= document.getElementById("nickname1");
    if (nickname1.innerHTML !== k) {
        nickname1.innerHTML= k + " (original nickname: §^-|_*[(@ATTISALVA@)]*_|-^§)"
    }
})

// Crowbaria, nickname
const nicknameFromAPI2= steam.getUserSummary("76561198175487278").then(function(k){
    return k.nickname;
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("Didn't make it")
})
nicknameFromAPI2.then(function(u){
    var nickname2= document.getElementById("nickname2");
    if (nickname2.innerHTML !== k) {
        nickname2.innerHTML= k + " (original nickname: Crowbaria)"
    }
})
```

I don't know what's wrong with this

I'm using Browserify to translate my code + Watchify for when I need to make several changes

What I kinda understand as far as I know:

-i need to first get the value by returning

-i need to .then 2 times

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208690/discussion-on-question-by-attisalva-cant-change-img-and-nicknames-picked-from-s).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's about CORS that blocks my code to be functional

Comment: No no, I'm not looking for an answer anymore